# Convert string to Date then minus some months

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres with Rails. I've two string fields which store date like this, field_1 = "2020.06.09", I 'm comparing them with `TO_DATE` function and they are working finr but now I want to compare them after adding 5 months in one field. What I've tried so far is:

`select * from users as u where TO_DATE(u.field_1, 'YYYY MM DD') > DATEADD(MONTH, 5, TO_DATE(u.field_2, 'YYYY MM DD'))`

can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you storing date values in a `text` column? That is a **really**, really bad idea. You should really fix that broken design before you do anything else.

Comment: I've got it working. instead of using DATEADD(MONTH, 5, TO_DATE(u.field_2, 'YYYY MM DD')), I've used TO_DATE(u.field_2, 'YYYY MM DD') + INTERVAL '5 MONTHS' and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `dateadd()` in Postgres (or standard SQL), you need to add an interval:

```
select *
from users u
where TO_DATE(u.field_1, 'YYYY MM DD') > to_date(u.field_2, 'yyyy mm dd') + interval '5 month';
```